# Help for a nested query

Tags: sql

my hosting company doesn't allow me to save query/view in **mysql** database (don't ask me ..why! i don't know), so i've to build an all in one nested query (that is difficult for my sql skills). 
My app is a simple "ticket managment system"
Here the table structure ticket_master

```
ticket_id
assignedto_user
...
```

The other table, for users

```
userid
username
```

I've to get the count of ticket per user, starting from the USERS table to include ALL users (either who haven't ticket opened).

The result must be

```
userid, username, tot_ticket
1, mr a, 3
2, mr b, Null (or zero)
3, mr c, 2
4, mr d, Null (or zero)
...
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select U.userid, U.username
    , Count(TM.ticket_id) As tot_ticket
From users As U
    Left Join ticket_master As TM
        On U.userid = TM.assignedto_user
Group By U.userid, U.username
```

Comment: `COUNT` can never be `NULL` presumably you would need `NULLIF` or whatever.

Comment: @Martin - Yes, yes. Occurred to me as I was re-reading my query.

Comment: @Martin - (I'm beating myself up more than anything. Must get more coffee...)

Comment: wow..it works... so simple ? how can is possible ?!? ;) i thought i'd to use some hyper-nested sql ... !

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    userid,
    username,
    COUNT(ticket_id)
FROM users
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ticket_master on users.userid = ticket_master.assignedto_user
```

Not much different than @Thomas answer, except that I would avoid the grouping if your user list is already unique.